# Not able to delete foreign key from table

Tags: mysql

I want to remove foreign key from table.
For that I am writing query

```
alter table mailid_invitation drop foreign key mailid_invitation_fk_user_id, 
drop column invited_by_id
```

But this is showing error

```
#1025 - Error on rename of '.\xrcwrn_sms\mailid_invitation' to 
'.\xrcwrn_sms\#sql2-12c0-524' (errno: 152)
```

How to resolve this.

Comment: Does it work if you do the two alterations separately?

Comment: No showing same error

Comment: have you looked at the **Related** questions to see if any of them match your situation?

Comment: `alter table my drop foreign key my_fk_id, drop column user_id;` is working properly for me but why it doesn't I dont know

Answer (score 0):

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

alter table table_Name drop foreign key key_name_here;
alter table mailid_invitation drop column invited_by_id;

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: Why are you dropping a table when all he wants to do is remove one column?

Comment: @Barmar: That first line is altering the table with a command to drop the fk constraint on the column, not dropping the table...

Comment: @williambq He edited his answer, he originally had `drop table`.

Comment: @Barmar: Very good. Sorry for the unencessary comment then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like a known mysql bug

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14347

check it out